# Akka Streams dropping messages?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am new to Akka Streams. I use it in Java. (akka-stream_2.12, version: 2.5.14).

I wrote the following class:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;

import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import akka.stream.javadsl.SourceQueueWithComplete;

public class AkkaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("VehicleSystem");
        final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem);

        SourceQueueWithComplete<Object> componentA_outPort1 = 
                Source.<Object>queue(100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()).async()
                    .to(Sink.foreach(str -> System.out.println(str)))
                    .run(materializer);

        for(int i=1; i<100000; i++)
            componentA_outPort1.offer("Akka rocks: " + i);

        System.in.read();
        actorSystem.terminate();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

I would expect the code to print 100000 messages, as this is the number of iterations. Instead, it just prints messages 1-101, and then messages starting at about 61000 (i.e "Akka rocks: 61000").

So most of the messages are not printed. Can you explain why?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the example. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hint to the problem here is the fact that "Done." is not printed to the console at the end. Instead it is printed somewhere either at the beginning or between the "Akka rocks" prints.

The reason for this is that `SourceQueue.offer` is asynchronous. It returns a `CompletionStage` and you are not waiting for its completion. The fact that some stream elements are "lost" can be explained instead by the [method's documentation](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/SourceQueue.html#offer-T-), specifically the following part:

> Additionally when using the backpressure overflowStrategy: - If the buffer is full the Future won't be completed until there is space in the buffer - Calling offer before the Future is completed in this case will return a failed Future

You can verify this by doing:

```
SourceQueueWithComplete<Object> componentA_outPort1 = 
    Source.<Object>queue(100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()).async()
        .to(Sink.foreach(str -> System.out.println(str)))
        .run(materializer);

for (int i=1; i<100000; i++) {
  CompletionStage<QueueOfferResult> result = componentA_outPort1.offer("Akka rocks: " + i);
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

You will see a lot of these "scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF@39471dfa[Not completed]"

In order to solve it, you should wait for the offer's CompletionStage to complete, effectively making the overall call synchronous, which seems to be your intention:

```
SourceQueueWithComplete<Object> componentA_outPort1 = 
    Source.<Object>queue(100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()).async()
        .to(Sink.foreach(str -> System.out.println(str)))
        .run(materializer);

for (int i=1; i<100000; i++) {
  componentA_outPort1.offer("Akka rocks: " + i).toCompletableFuture().join();
}
```

Still "Done" will not necessarily be printed at the end, because the completion of the offer only guarantees you that the queue accepted the element, not that it was completely processed. Also, keep in mind that the `actorSystem.terminate()` is also asynchronous.

The above approach works for your case, but in some cases it may not be desirable to block the current thread. For a simple case like yours, it can be easily avoided by using a different `Source`:

```
Source.range(1,  1000).map(i -> "Akka rocks: " + i)
```

For more complex cases, consider other static methods of Source, like `Source.from` which takes an Iterable, or `Source.fromIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. The idiomatic way to feed a `SourceQueue` is with another `Source` (as Pedro mentioned in his answer).
2. You're likely terminating the actor system before your stream has finished processing.

Shut down the system once the materialized value of the sink has completed:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import akka.Done;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Keep;
import akka.stream.javadsl.RunnableGraph;
// other imports...

Sink<String, CompletionStage<Done>> sink =
  Sink.foreach(str -> System.out.println(str));

Source<String, SourceQueueWithComplete<String>> outPort =
  Source.<String>queue(100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()).async();

RunnableGraph<Pair<SourceQueueWithComplete<String>, CompletionStage<Done>>> stream =
  outPort.toMat(sink, Keep.both());

Pair<SourceQueueWithComplete<String>, CompletionStage<Done>> pair = stream.run();

Source.range(1, 100000)
  .map(i -> "Akka rocks: " + i)
  .mapAsync(1, s -> pair.first().offer(s))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore(), materializer);

pair.second().thenRun(() -> actorSystem.terminate());
```

Comment: The example I posted is a simplified version of what I try to achieve. In the actual code, I want to send events to the stream, and the events may arrive at different times. So a simple Source with a range is not sufficient. I also definitely want an asyncronous boundary. Is your solution with .mapAsync different from my solution with .async(), concerning the asyncronous processing?

Comment: Using `mapAsync` and defining an asynchronous boundary with `.async` are not the same. Read this [blog post](https://blog.colinbreck.com/maximizing-throughput-for-akka-streams/) for more details. You might want to experiment with adjusting the parallelism level (the first parameter to `mapAsync`).